# Growth Rate. A precise definition.

Tags: soft-question, terminology, finance

Recently I came across a problem (see statement below) *growth rate* . During my attempts to solve the exercise I concluded that I do not know the meaning of need backup *growth rate* when this rate is noconstant and varies finds a discrete parameter.

> **Problem ( growth rate ).** The current circulation a certain journal is 5000 copies per week. Knowing that owner of Journal projects a growth rate of $6+8\cdot t^{\frac{3}{5}}$ copies to week, hence the $t$ weeks, over the next five years, the newspaper circulation in about 150 weeks is how many copies ?

***Update.** The answer suggested by the source of this problem is 20.050 copies*

It seems to me that understanding the precise meaning of *growth rate* is determining how to suitable the formula to solve the exercise.

I did an internet search and found multiple meanings that lead to various formulas : population growth , birth rate, death rate , net profit rate , etc. ...

**Observation.** I have no problem as algebraic manipulations.

> **My first question is:** What is the concept of *growth rate* that is suitable for use in the exercise below ? How to apply it to solve the problem? This concept is just a convention ?

\;

> **Second question:** What are the different concepts of rate of growth that exist and how to use them ? Is there any reference?

Comment: Are you sure that 20.050 is the right answer?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, it is not a well-defined term.  I can see the following ways to read the problem:

1. the circulation in week $t$ is $6+8t^{\frac 35}$ more copies than in week $t-1$.  I would use this one, so you just need to sum $6+8t^{\frac 35}$ from $1$ to $150$ and add $5000$ to get your answer.
2. the circulation in week $t$ is $1+(6+8t^{\frac 35})$ times that in week $t-1$.  This doesn't make sense with this value, but if you were given a $10\%$ growth rate it would
3. the circulation in week $t$ is $6+8t^{\frac 35}$ total copies.  This doesn't match your $5000$ value for a reasonable value of $t$.  I wouldn't call this a growth rate, but I have seen it done.

Comment: *Thanks and +1. After a while I discovered that the answer given by the source of this problem is 20.050 copies*

Answer (score 1):

Growth rate means derivative in every example I have ever seen. When used in a discrete situation, as here, it is assumed that we are using a continuous model of a discrete situation. This is very common in applied math and physics, like thermodynamics.

Comment: OK. Recently I realized that his point of view refers to something we can call "discrete derivative". Could you explain your point of view? An example? I thank you.